# Code coverage tool for Mule in Eclipse

Tags: java, unit-testing, code-coverage, mule, functional-testing

Is there any code coverage tool with a plugin for `Eclipse` for `Mule`.

I'm looking for a tool that can highlight in `mule-config` lines covered, % covered and things like that. Curious what people use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an interesting project currently under development called [Munit](https://github.com/mulesoft/munit/wiki) that might fit your needs.

The coverage feature is not yet implemented but i planned for the [next release](https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?mode=hide&requestId=13041)

Comment: Thanks for pointing to a promising project. I can't wait to give it a try

Answer (score 0):

The code coverage is used in order to know how many lines of code are covered. But, I think that you want to know how many lines are covered in your mule-config.xml right? As far I know there are no tools for that.